# need to make password less login for same linux server with same user

Tags: linux, unix

i need to make passwordless login for same linux server with same user.

```
[airwide@eir ~]$ hostname -i
10.3.7.73
[airwide@eir ~]$ ssh airwide@10.3.7.73
airwide@10.3.7.73's password:
```

how can make to passwordless for same server?

Comment: This question would probably get a better response on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password-free login via SSH is managed using SSH keys. You can generate a keypair using the command `ssh-keygen`. The ssh keypair is usually stored in `~/.ssh` in a pair of files named `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`. When you use SSH to connect to a server, the SSH command will look for a private key in `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, and will attempt to authenticate using that key. In order to authorize the key, you will need to place the public key into your `authorized_keys` file:

```
`cat ~/./ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
```

Once you've done that, you will be able to use SSH to connect without a password from the server where the `id_rsa` file is to the server that has the content of `id_rsa.pub` in its `authorized_keys` file. (You can do this for same-server, as in your question, or between multiple servers. Either way, it's the same process.)

Answer (score 1):

Add server's private key in known host key under .ssh folder.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for ssh keys. You can create one by entering `ssh-keygen`. This wil create a public key and a private key. You place the public key on the remote server, and then you can use SSH without a password.

More details, and howto:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys